# Embedding Subgroup in Direct Product in Magma

Tags: group-theory, magma-cas

I am using magma and want to consider a group $H$ as a subgroup of the direct product $H \times G$, written in magma as DirectProduct(H,G).

Right now I am having to use the subgroup generator construction, as in the following example.

It feels like there must be a much simpler way that I am missing!

A further question is how do I simply select an element of $G \setminus H$? An element of $G$ can be chosen by Rep(G), but I am not sure how to ensure this is not in $H$...

*Example:*

```
 H := CyclicGroup(8);
 G := DirectProduct(H,CyclicGroup(2))
 H := sub<G | (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)>;
```

Comment: This is quite clearly explained in the hand book: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/639#7119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> H := CyclicGroup(8);
> G, inj := DirectProduct(H,CyclicGroup(2));
> H := Image(inj[1]);
> H;
Permutation group H acting on a set of cardinality 10
Order = 8 = 2^3
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```